# Ajax passing data to php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to my PHP script to handle some stuff and generate some items.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "test.php", 
    data: "album="+ this.title,
    success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
    }
});
```

In my PHP file I try to retrieve the album name. Though when I validate it, I created an alert to show what the `albumname` is I get nothing, I try to get the album name by `$albumname = $_GET['album'];`

Though it will say undefined :/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are sending a POST AJAX request so use `$albumname = $_POST['album'];` on your server to fetch the value. Also I would recommend you writing the request like this in order to ensure proper encoding:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'test.php', 
    data: { album: this.title },
    success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
    }
});
```

or in its shorter form:

```
$.post('test.php', { album: this.title }, function() {
    content.html(response);
});
```

and if you wanted to use a GET request:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test.php', 
    data: { album: this.title },
    success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
    }
});
```

or in its shorter form:

```
$.get('test.php', { album: this.title }, function() {
    content.html(response);
});
```

and now on your server you wil be able to use `$albumname = $_GET['album'];`. Be careful though with AJAX GET requests as they might be cached by some browsers. To avoid caching them you could set the `cache: false` setting.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me using GET. Couldn't get this figured out :/ thanks a bunch!

Comment: $.get('test.php', { album: this.title } i want to ask how to send two values

Comment: @M.chaudhry you may have found this already, but for future readers, this is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), so to send multiple values, you just add another one with a comma like so: `$.get('test.php', { album: this.title, song: that.title });`

Answer (score 12):

Try sending the data like this:

```
var data = {};
data.album = this.title;
```

Then you can access it like

```
$_POST['album']
```

Notice not a 'GET'

Answer (score 4):

You can also use bellow code for pass data using ajax.

```
var dataString = "album" + title;
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'test.php', 
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'test.php',
data: { album: this.title },
success: function(response) {
content.html(response);
}
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).