# Form Submit Without Page Refreshing- jQuery/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm really new to this site and new to web design. Lately, I'd been trying so hard to design a web page for days/weeks and I ended up stuck at "Contact Form".

I used Bootstrap to write a form that pop up from a modal window. Plus, I also linked a remote contact form so I can just link it up for different pages.

However I've got not much knowledge of php and jquery to validate and submit my form on the fly at that modal page without refreshing the page. I am stuck her for days going a week. Here is my code please help.

I linked remote contact form from homepage like this :

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Subscribe! <b class=".glyphicon-triangle-bottom:before">▼</b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="form/contactForm.php" data-target="#contactmodal" role="button"><i id="ddicons" class="fa fa-envelope-square"></i> Newsletter</a></li>
```

And the linked contactForm.php goes like this :

```
UPDATED CHECK BELOW
```

and the mailform.php is like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "myemail@email.com";

    $email_subject = "Newsletter Subscription";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['country']) ||

        !isset($_POST['gender']) ||

        !isset($_POST['terms'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $inputName = $_POST['name']; // required

    $inputEmail = $_POST['email']; // required

    $country = $_POST['country']; // required

    $gender = $_POST['gender']; // not required

    $terms = $_POST['terms']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$inputEmail)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$inputName)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }


  if(strlen($inputCountry) < 1) {

    $error_message .= 'Please select your country.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

  if(strlen($inputGender) < 1) {

    $error_message .= 'Please select your gender.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($inputName)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($inputEmail)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($inputCountry)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Gender: ".clean_string($inputGender)."\n"; 




// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Problem:

I've got no idea what going on now. The homepage modal does load the remote form but the submit button isn't working and when it does, it refreshes. I do wish all the input in the form are required.

So far I have this as my contact form. Country: Gender : Agree: and Submit: are not working well.. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Ajax Contact Form</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

        var proceed = true;
        //simple validation at client's end
        //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
        $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            //check invalid email
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   
        });

        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {
            //get input field values data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
                'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
                'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            };

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                    $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
                }
                $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- MAIL MODAL -->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Join Nexeu Mailing List!</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">


    <!--- Form --->
    <form action="mailform.php" class="form-horizontal" id="contact_form" method="post" name="modalform" role="form"/>
    <fieldset>
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
    <div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
    <div id="contact_results"></div>
    <div id="contact_body">


          <!-- Name input-->
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="name"><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span></label>
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" maxlength="180" required="true" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- e-mail input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="email"><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" required="true" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
        <!-- Country Select -->
        <div id="choosecountry" class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="subject"><span>Country <span class="required">*</span></span></label>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <select id="country" name="subject" class="form-control" title="Select Country..." required>
              <option value="">Select Country...</option>
              <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
              <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
              <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
              <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
              <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
              <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
              <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
              <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
              <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
              <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
              <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
              <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
              <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
              <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
              <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
              <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
              <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
              <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
              <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
              <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
              <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
              <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
              <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
              <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
              <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
              <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
              <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
              <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
              <option value="Cabo Verde">Cabo Verde</option>
              <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
              <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
              <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
              <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
              <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
              <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
              <option value="China">China</option>
              <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
              <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
              <option value="Congo, Republic of the">Congo, Republic of the</option>
              <option value="Congo, Democratic Republic of the">Congo, Democratic Republic of the</option>
              <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
              <option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
              <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
              <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
              <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
              <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
              <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
              <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
              <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
              <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
              <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
              <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
              <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
              <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
              <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
              <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
              <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
              <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
              <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
              <option value="France">France</option>
              <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
              <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
              <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
              <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
              <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
              <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
              <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
              <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
              <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
              <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
              <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
              <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
              <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
              <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
              <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
              <option value="India">India</option>
              <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
              <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
              <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
              <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
              <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
              <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
              <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
              <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
              <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
              <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
              <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
              <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
              <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
              <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
              <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
              <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
              <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
              <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
              <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
              <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
              <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
              <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
              <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
              <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
              <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
              <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
              <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
              <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
              <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
              <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
              <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
              <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
              <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
              <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
              <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
              <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
              <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
              <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
              <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
              <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
              <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
              <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
              <option value="Myanmar (Burma)">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
              <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
              <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
              <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
              <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
              <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
              <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
              <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
              <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
              <option value="North Korea">North Korea</option>
              <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
              <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
              <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
              <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
              <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
              <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
              <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
              <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
              <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
              <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
              <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
              <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
              <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
              <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
              <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
              <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
              <option value="St. Kitts and Nevis">St. Kitts and Nevis</option>
              <option value="St. Lucia">St. Lucia</option>
              <option value="St. Vincent and The Grenadines">St. Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
              <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
              <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
              <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
              <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
              <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
              <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
              <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
              <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
              <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
              <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
              <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
              <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
              <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
              <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
              <option value="South Korea">South Korea</option>
              <option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
              <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
              <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
              <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
              <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
              <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
              <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
              <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
              <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
              <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
              <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
              <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
              <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
              <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
              <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
              <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
              <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
              <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
              <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
              <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
              <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
              <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
              <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
              <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
              <option value="UK (United Kingdom)">UK (United Kingdom)</option>
              <option value="USA (United States of America)">USA (United States of America)</option>
              <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
              <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
              <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
              <option value="Vatican City (Holy See)">Vatican City (Holy See)</option>
              <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
              <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
              <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
              <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
              <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
          <!-- Gender Select -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="gender">Gender </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="btn-group" id="genderbtn" name="gender" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"required>Female</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"required>Other</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <!--- Agreement Button --->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                  <input id="terms" type="checkbox" for="agree" name="agree" value="agree" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
                  Agree with the terms and conditions </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <button id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit btn btn-custom">Submit!</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
    </form>
<!--- /Form ---> 
</div><!-- end modal-body -->
<div class="modal-footer"></div>
<!-- end modal-footer --> 

<!-- end mailmodal --> 
<!-- /MAIL MODAL -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can send your data to server side using ajax. It wont refresh your page. You can also refer this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782230/ajax-passing-data-to-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

You need use ajax, here a example: http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form

Comment: Thanks! it really get me somewhere I want to achieve :D

Answer (score 0):

You may use bellow code for form submit without refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#login-form-submit").click(function(){
                var username = $("#login-form-username").val();
                var password = $("#login-form-password").val();

                if(username == ""){
                    alert("Please Enter Email.");
                    $("#login-form-username").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if(password == "")
                {
                    alert("Please Enter Password.");
                    $("#login-form-password").focus();
                    return false;
                }

                var form = document.getElementById('login-form');
                formdata2 = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url : "controller/ajax/check_login.php",
                    cache : false,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    data : formdata2,
                    type : 'post',
                    success : function(data) {
                        if (data == 1) {
                            alert('success');
                        }else {
                            alert('Invalid Authentication.');
                        }
                    }
                });
               return false;
            });
        });
```