# How to echo an ajax variable in PHP file

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send a variable from one PHP file to another PHP file and echo it:

```js
<script>
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AjaxCallTest.php',
        data: ({Imgname:"13"}),
        success: function() {
            alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
<script>
```

And then in the receiving PHP file (`AjaxCallTest.php`):

```php
<?php
    $temp = $_POST['Imgname'];
    echo $temp;
?>
```

but AjaxCallTest file doesn't echo anything? I need to get this variable and echo it. Note that I've included jQuery library in my code but I didn't include it in `AjaxCallTest.php`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax passing data to php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782230/ajax-passing-data-to-php-script)

Comment: you are missing a slash in the ending <script> tag

Answer (score 1):

replace this line `data: ({Imgname:"13"}),` with `data: {"Imgname":"13"}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked! Notice the closing <script> tag

I also added the return result to check the echo in 'AjaxCallTest.php'

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AjaxCallTest.php',
        data: ({Imgname:"13"}),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result + ' form was submitted');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me. One error I could find is that you didnt closed the script tag correctly. close the script tag.

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AjaxCallTest.php',
        data: ({Imgname:"13"}),
        success: function() {
            alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
<script>
```