# ajax on radio button click

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

//on below code output  occured is  Undefined index: policy , how can i get the value of variable policy on controller

//product_view.php

```
    $(".product").on('change', function(){ 
    var policy= "gggggggggggg";
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
//alert(policy);
  $.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: base_url+"/sales/index.php/Add_AMC/Insurance_chg",
  data: policy,
  success: function( response ) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
});

//Add_amc.php controller
//function Insurance_chg(){
        $product=$_POST['policy'];
        echo $product;die();
    }
```

Comment: Use JSON structure to send data on server and retrieve post data by iterate JSON in php

Comment: Hi Shubhangi, please refer to given post for your solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782230/ajax-passing-data-to-php-script

Comment: your ajax call look good,so problem maybe on radio button side,as it's showing undefined index error so make sure it's getting valid radio button id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem may be at sending data....

```
     $(".product").on('change', function(){ 
    var policy= "gggggggggggg";
    //var base_url = 'window.location.origin';
//alert(policy);
  $.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
   url:<?php echo base_url('sales/index.php/Add_AMC/Insurance_chg');?>,
  data: {policy:policy},
  success: function( response ) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
});
```

OR you can send your data as..

```
data:'policy='+policy,
```

In codeigniter you can use the `base_url()` by loading the `url` helper.So not need to define `base_url` like this...
So change

```
url: base_url+"/sales/index.php/Add_AMC/Insurance_chg",
```

to

```
url:<?php echo base_url('sales/index.php/Add_AMC/Insurance_chg');?>,
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(".product").on('change', function(){ 
    var policy= "gggggggggggg";
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    var var_data = "policy="+ policy;
  $.ajax( {
     type: "POST",
     url: base_url+"/sales/index.php/Add_AMC/Insurance_chg",
     data: var_data,
     success: function( response ) {
       alert(response);
     }
  });
});
```